# Change makeInput Label text color

Tags: flutter

I was trying to build a simple form in flutter and I wanted to make the label text color white.
The `Email`, `Password`  and `Confirm Password`.

```dart
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    FadeAnimation(
      1.2,
      makeInput(label: "Email"),
    ),
    FadeAnimation(
      1.3,
      makeInput(label: "Password", obscureText: true),
    ),
    FadeAnimation(
      1.4,
      makeInput(label: "Confirm Password", obscureText: true),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: what is the problem you're facing with achieving this task? In `flutter` input labels are styled via the `decoration` field which requires an `InputDecoration` class.

Comment: @RohanThacker Yes thank you but I'm still new to this and sometimes I'm facing problems with small things. Sorry.

Comment: No problem, Updated that field and you will be able to set the label color.